# Save the client id prestashop again in another table

Tags: prestashop

I created a new field in the form of creating customer backoffice prestashop.

I need this field is kept on a table that is not the user with the id of the new customer that will create as I get the go and where you advise me to do all these calls to the database.

Comment: your question is not clear...

Comment: get solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend for greater flexibility and stability to a call every time to the database.